# Windows 10 program/area isolation

Tags: windows-10

I would like to have two Windows 10 Pro installations activated with the same serial number, the first is having program set "A" installed, the second having program set "B" installed. (E.g. imagine a "Work" installation and a "Game" installation, although the use case is a bit more complex.)

Right now I do this by creating a clean Win10 installation on SSD 1, activating, creating a System Image and then cloning that on SSD 2. Then I install program set "A" on SSD 1 and program set "B" on SSD 2. And basically I switch the SSDs between uses.

Since only one Win10 installation is active (only one SSD is attached and booted from), this is in alignment with Win10 licensing (and with many other programs' licensing terms as well).

Now, with Linux, I can install one OS and mount filesystems, use NFS, or layering FS, etc. I don't want to network boot, IPXE, etc. I don't want to use a VM, that brings its own compatibility problems.

I would like to have only one install of the OS, updated only by the administrator, and have different sets of programs available, one set of programs completely isolated from the others (so: no registry trace, no DLL pollution from the other set, no work documents and temporary files shared, etc.). Is this possible with Win10?

Comment: **Since only one Win10 installation is active (only one SSD is attached and booted from), this is in alignment with Win10 licensing (and with many other programs' licensing terms as well).** - It actually isn't.

Comment: Can you provide link for your claim about the licencing? I have same concerns as Ramhound expressed above, but I know that Microsoft is supporting use cases with multiple instances and one base image. For such use case relaxed licencing makes total sense.

Comment: A future version of Windows 10 Enterprise will suppose what is called InPrivate Desktop.  It will isolate applications, it works similarly to Sandboxie, but would be built into Windows.  It would not provide you complete install isolation, but that isn't possible with Sandboxie, and that simply requires multiple installations.

Comment: I am using the licensing info from here: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/Licensing/product-licensing/products.aspx

Comment: Desktop Operating Systems
Device License
    1. Customer may install one copy of the software on a Licensed Device or within a local virtual hardware system on a Licensed Device for each License it acquires.
    2. Customer may use the software on up to two processors.
    3. Local use is permitted for any user.
    4. Remote use is permitted for the Primary User of the Licensed Device and for any other user from another Licensed Device or a Windows VDA Licensed Device.
    5. Only one user may access and use the software at a time.

Comment: 6. Customer may connect up to 20 devices to the Licensed Device for file sharing, printing, Internet Information Services, Internet Connection Sharing or telephony services.
    7. An unlimited number of connections are allowed for KMS activation or similar technology.

Comment: An OS image is not an installation. When you remove the SSD it ceases functioning as an OS. (Is a zip-ped OS an installation?) An OS is installed if it is capable of operating as an OS: boot, enter protected mode, start the kernel etc. An OS image on a  physically disconnected SSD is not able to do that.

Comment: I have 2 SSDs, using on the very same computer (so the activation is correct), but only one SSD is actually containing an OS capable of functioning as OS, the physically connected one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closest native solution I can think of is [differencing VHDX](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc720381(v=ws.10).aspx) with [native boot](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc720381(v=ws.10).aspx). You would have one parent VHDX disk image with two children VHDX differential images that you would boot into.

✔ native performance
✔ one install of the OS
✘ updated only by the administrator ([only leaf/children vhdx can be edited](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc720381(v=ws.10).aspx))
✔ completely isolated from the others
❔ licencing

**Example**

[image: example]

Comment: This looks promising, but isn't this a virtual server (VM) solution? VMware, VirtualBox has this as well.

Comment: No, not really. The VHDX is disk image format used by Hyper-V. I guess VMware or VirtualBox can support this disk format along their own native one. And there is probably extra (virtualization) layer between OS and HDD that handles read/write calls. But the overhead has to be very small from my experience. Everything else is bare metal.

Comment: Hyper-V is a hypervisor. And so it theoretically provides the correct isolation, and I actually will look into your proposed solution, but as I know, VMs have various hardware issues (DX, OpenGL support, latest hardware features). Thank you for your answer!

Comment: I might have confuse you with mentioning Hyper-V. The support for VHDX is available natively in Windows and Windows bootloader. It would be mistake to expect any of the hardware issues you named.

Comment: After 3 years LOL, I am accepting this solution. There are some small issues to work around (Bitlocker), but in general, it is mature and stable. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Windows is not designed to do this natively.  However, you can do this through 3rd party software.  It is called sandboxing.  [Sandboxie](https://www.sandboxie.com/) is a popular piece of software that does this, but I have not personally used this software, or sandboxing software in general.  Im sure you can find other sandboxing software to do this as well, as the concept has been around for a long time.

Comment: I have my experience with Sandboxie, and it is not a perfect sandbox. That time I was using it actually someone was able to hack and bypass the boundary control...